# How to improve on this "twolines" decoration?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

I'm typesetting an article on graphical calculus in tensor categories in TikZ and I wanted to define a decoration that draws two parallel lines at the same time. Here is my first try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}

\begin{document}
    \pgfdeclaredecoration{twolines}{initial}
    {
        \state{initial}[width=2pt]
        {
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{1pt}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{1pt}}
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1pt}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{-1pt}}
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        }
    }
    \tikz[decoration=twolines]{
        \coordinate (T) at (0.6,0);
        \coordinate (N) at (0,0.2);
        \draw[decorate,knot=black] (T) to[out=-90,in=-90] (N) -- (0,1);
        \draw[decorate,knot=black] (0,-1) node[below] {$X \otimes Y$} -- ($(0,0)-(N)$) to[out=90,in=90] (T);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, it kind of works, but it's not ideal. The individual line segments should be connected, and ideally, curved. I could just decrease "width" to a ridiculously short length (say 0.1pt), but that seems to slow big pictures down a lot. Is there a nicer way to fix the problems?

Edit: I tried percusse's excellent suggestion to just use the "double" option, which is probably very fast and doesn't even need decorations. However, it seems that it doesn't play well with the "knots" library. Combining "double" and "knot=black" seems to overwrite the "double" option.

Edit 2: My question is about tikz decorations and not about general ways to draw my diagram, *especially none including pstricks*.

Edit 3: Workarounds for my particular example aren't very interesting since it's easily done in TikZ or with other libraries. I'm interested in writing a good decoration.

Comment: I think you can get away with `double` in many cases.

Comment: @percusse, that's cool, I didn't know about it, since I only looked in the decorations documentation. However, my actual usecase involves Andrew Stacey's "knots" package and it seems not to be compatible with double. I'll update my question.

Comment: knots or `braids`?

Comment: `knots`, see my update.

Comment: Which package brings that library?

Comment: I believe it's in `spath3`: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3

Comment: `double` doesn't work with `knot` because `knot` invokes `double` internally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`knot` and `double` don't work together because the `double` mechanism is how `knot` overwrites any underlying paths: it uses `double` with the sidelines set to the background colour and the central colour the main colour (this is opposite to how `double` is intended to be used).  If you want the main path to itself be `double`d then you need to draw the path three times: outermost with the background colour, middle with the main colour, and then innermost with the background colour again.  This isn't natively provided for in TikZ (and nor in the `knots` package) but can be easily done with a `preaction`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193243/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (T) at (.6,0);
\coordinate (N) at (0,0.2);

\draw[double] (T) to[out=-90,in=-90] (N) -- (0,1);
\draw[double,preaction={draw=white,double=none,line width=4pt}] (0,-1) node[below] {$X \otimes Y$} -- ($(0,0)-(N)$) to[out=90,in=90] (T);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Knot path with double]

If you want to specify your path as a single path with a self-intersection, you should use the `knot` environment (from the `knots` package) instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193243/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (T) at (.6,0);
\coordinate (N) at (0,0.2);

\begin{knot}[
  consider self intersections=true,
  ignore endpoint intersections=false,
  clip width=2,
]
\strand[double] (0,-1) node[below] {$X \otimes Y$} -- ($(0,0)-(N)$) to[out=90,in=90] (T) to[out=-90,in=-90] (N) -- (0,1);
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: with the knot environment]

Comment: Your second example doesn't work on my computer, though.

Comment: @Turion What's the error?  It might be a version issue.

Comment: TikZ 3 and knots 1.0. It looks like this: ![this](http://i58.tinypic.com/5d546.png)

Answer (score 8):

I can propose a solution (more or less accurate) in `pstricks` but it should not be difficult to adapt it to `tikz-pdf`, as the code is simple. It's based on the fact that the curve you want is close to a `strophoid` and that one can plot it using its `polar equation`.

```
        \documentclass[11pt, a4paper,svgnames,pdf]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage{pst-plot}
        \usepackage{pst-node} 

        \begin{document}

        \psset{yunit=8mm, xunit=8mm, labelsep=0pt , linewidth=1pt,linecolor=IndianRed, doubleline=true,  plotpoints=200,plotstyle=curve, polarplot, algebraic}%
        \Rnode{S}{\psset{}
        \psplot{-1.35}{0}{0.5*cos(2*x)/cos(x)} \psplot[border =1pt]{0}{1.35}{0.5*cos(2*x)/cos(x)}}
        \uput{0.35cm}[dl](S){$X\bigotimes Y $}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

**Added**: Hopefully a better fitting solution. Note that global change in the unit will require an adjustement of the elliptic arc x-diameter in the code:

```
        \documentclass[11pt, a4paper,svgnames,pdf]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage{pst-plot}
        \usepackage{pst-node}

        \begin{document}
        \pspicture%
        \psset{labelsep=0pt , linewidth=1pt,linecolor=IndianRed, doubleline=true}%
        \Rnode{S}{%
          \psline(0,1.6)(0,0.6)\psarc(0.80,0.6){0.8}{179}{271}
           \psellipticarcn(0.8,0)(0.30, 0.257){90}{-90}
          \psarc[border = 1pt, bordercolor = white](0.80,-0.6){0.8}{89}{181}\psline(0,-0.6)(0,-1.6)
          }
        \uput{1.8}[d](S){$X\bigotimes Y $}
        \endpspicture

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer how to improve the decoration, right? The way how the curve looks exactly is irrelevant.

Comment: No, I proposed a curve that more or less had the look of your picture, and was a smooth curve. But it was not clear to me what you exactly wanted. The soultuion might come from a piecewise defined function.

Comment: My question is "How to improve on this twolines decoration", so the question is how to improve the decoration, not the curve.

Comment: Sorry, your solution does look very good, thank you for the effort anyways!

Comment: I have another idea, that I'll fine-tune and propose in a moment.

Comment: @Turion: I've added another solution. Hope it fits better what you want.

Comment: You haven't really understood what I'm aiming at. I asked about __how to improve the TikZ decoration__, not how to draw the diagram differently with pstricks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16018/discussion-between-bernard-and-turion).

Answer (score 4):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-0.11,0)(1,5)
\psset{linecolor=IndianRed,doubleline}
\psecurve(0,0)(0,1.99)(0.2,2.4)(0.5,2.7)(0.8,2.7)(0.9,2.49)(0.9,2)
\psecurve[border=1pt](0.9,3)(0.9,2.51)(0.8,2.3)(0.5,2.3)(0.2,2.6)(0,3.01)(0,5)
\psline(0,2.01)  \psline(0,3)(0,5)
\uput{0.35cm}[-90](0,0){$X\bigotimes Y $}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]