# Tikz: Drawing railway tracks

Tags: tikz-pgf

I like to draw a double line such that the gap between the two lines is transparent. My purpose is to draw railway tracks:

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

 \tikzstyle{track}=[
   postaction={draw=gray,densely dashed,line width=14pt},
   postaction={draw=black,double distance=8pt,line width=2pt},
   postaction={draw=gray,densely dashed,line width=8pt},]

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw[track] (-5,27) to[out=  0,in=180] ( 5,33) 
                      to[out=  0,in= 90] ( 7,25) 
                      to[out=270,in=  0] (-5,27);

 \draw[track] (-4,10) to (0,10) to[out=  0,in=270] (4,16);
 \draw[track] (12,10) to (8,10) to[out=180,in=270] (4,16) to (4,20);

 \draw[track] (-4,0) to (12,0);

 \draw[track] (0,0) to[out=  0,in=270] (3,2) 
                    to[out= 90,in=270] (1,4)
                    to[out= 90,in=180] (4,6) 
                    to[out=  0,in=120] (8,5) 
                    to[out=300,in=  0] (4,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

The second postaction draws a double line, but the gap between the two lines is not transparent. Therefore, I made the third postaction. But I expect that the tracks will look much more realistic (in particular at the switches) if the gap of the double lines is transparent. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Good question, and a really clever way to draw the sleepers!

Comment: `double distance` (or simply `double`) draws the path twice---one with the base color, and one with the inbetween color. If you specify `double=transparent`, so that the inbetween color is transparent, you will see that instead of getting a white fill, it is all solid black. If you want a different solution than your own, `double distance` might not be the appropriate command. A different approach could be to instead draw two black lines---one shifted to the left and one shifted to the right.

Comment: I tried the solution of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102975/draw-additional-parallel-paths-in-tikz without success: The decorations in the postactions were not drawn along the path.

Comment: The first try of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193243/how-to-improve-on-this-twolines-decoration/193668#193668 seems to be quite close, but I could not make it working. The other solutions there use knots or double which have the same non-transparent issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be done (admittedly with some effort) using fadings and decorations. The following is I guess more proof-of-concept than anything else but might prove useful:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,fit,fadings}

% Layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{sleeper}
\pgfdeclarelayer{rail}
\pgfsetlayers{sleeper,rail,main}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{tracks}{final}{%
\state{final}{%
  \pgftransformreset% <- I think is possibly vital.
  %
  % Get bounding box of decorated path as a node.
  % Must do it this way using basic layer.
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current path bounding box}{south west}}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@1}\pgfpointorigin%
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current path bounding box}{north east}}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@2}\pgfpointorigin%
  \node [fit=(@1)(@2), inner sep=\railsep+2*\railwidth] (@@) {};
  %
  % Create a fading for the track.
  \pgfinterruptpicture%
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tracks]
    \path[draw=transparent!0, line width=\railsep+2*\railwidth, 
     postaction={draw=transparent!100, line width=\railsep}] 
      \pgfextra{\pgfsetpath\pgfdecoratedpath};
    \useasboundingbox (@@.south west) (@@.north east);
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \endpgfinterruptpicture
  %
  % Draw sleepers.
  \ifx\sleeperlayer\emptylayer\else\pgfonlayer{\sleeperlayer}\fi%
  \draw [draw=\sleepercolor,line width=\sleeperlength, dash pattern=on \sleeperwidth off \sleepersep, every sleeper/.try]
    \pgfextra{\pgfsetpath\pgfdecoratedpath};
  \ifx\sleeperlayer\emptylayer\else\endpgfonlayer\fi%
  %
  % Draw the track
  \ifx\raillayer\emptylayer\else\pgfonlayer{\raillayer}\fi%
  \fill [path fading=tracks, fit fading=false, 
    fading transform={shift=(@@.center)}, fill=\railcolor] 
   (@@.south west) rectangle (@@.north east);
   \ifx\raillayer\emptylayer\else\endpgfonlayer\fi%
}
}
\def\emptylayer{}
\tikzset{%
  track/.style={
    decoration=tracks, decorate
  },
  decorations/.cd,
    rail sep/.store in=\railsep,
    rail width/.store in=\railwidth,
    rail color/.store in=\railcolor,
    rail layer/.store in=\raillayer,
    sleeper sep/.store in=\sleepersep,
    sleeper width/.store in=\sleeperwidth,
    sleeper length/.store in=\sleeperlength,
    sleeper color/.store in=\sleepercolor,
    sleeper layer/.store in=\sleeperlayer,
    rail sep=4pt,
    rail width=1pt,
    rail color=black,
    rail layer=rail,
    sleeper sep=6pt,
    sleeper width=1pt,
    sleeper length=10pt,
    sleeper color=gray,
    sleeper layer=sleeper,
}
\begin{document}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [track] (-2,5) to (0,5) to[out=  0,in=270] (2,8);
\draw [track] (6,5) to (4,5) to[out=180,in=270] (2,8) to (2,10);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remark: If you wanted to add the background, you can, there are `z-layers` in TikZ, it's a bit complicated (you need to scope everything) but it works.

Comment: This solves my problem. Additionally, I will split the decoration into two such that I can draw all sleepers at a layer in a first step and then draw all rails on another layer--like tracks are build in practice.

Comment: @user61383 you don't necessarily have to split the decoration as the the decoration can use different layers. See the updated answer

Comment: Why do you think the reset is vital? I tried commenting it out and couldn't tell any difference. I was trying to figure out how to draw outlined tracks in one step. I assumed commenting it out would break everything, but wanted to know what it did. However, I couldn't tell the difference. (I also couldn't figure out how to combine my steps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418299/ :(. At least, I think I could combine them by changing the decoration code more radically, but I was trying to do it without that & just using e.g. `preaction`/`postaction`. Obviously a dumb idea!)

Comment: This used to work but stopped (I suspect after an update of tikz).  The track lines show up at the wrong places.  The MWE in the original post works.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is the best suggestion I have:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzstyle{track}=[
    postaction={draw=gray,densely dashed,line width=14pt},
    postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={curveto,raise=4pt},line width=2pt},
    postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={curveto,raise=-4pt},line width=2pt}]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \path[track] (-5,27)    to[out=  0,in=180] ( 5,33) 
                            to[out=  0,in= 90] ( 7,25) 
                            to[out=270,in=  0] (-5,27);

    \path[track] (-4,10)    to ( 0,10) to[out=  0,in=270] (4,16);
    \path[track] (12,10)    to ( 8,10) to[out=180,in=270] (4,16) to (4,20);

    \path[track] (-4, 0)    to (12, 0);

    \path[track] ( 0, 0)    to[out=  0,in=270] (3,2) 
                            to[out= 90,in=270] (1,4)
                            to[out= 90,in=180] (4,6) 
                            to[out=  0,in=120] (8,5) 
                            to[out=300,in=  0] (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, this creates a problem at the endpoints, where the rails meet at the center line. By defining a custom decoration (somewhat beyond my experience), you might be able to also make the `curveto` line start at a raised point. If not, a crude workaround would be to erase the endpoints by drawing a white rectangle on top of them.

[image: output example]

Comment: You need to draw the sleepers in a first pass, then the rails in a second pass.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach that uses `blend group`.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \path[save path=\cloud](0,0)..controls(5,5)..(10,0);
    \path[save path=\hill](0,5)..controls(0,0)and(10,0)..(10,5);
    \begin{scope}[blend group=darken]
        \begin{scope}[dash pattern=on2off4,line width=12,darkgray]
            \draw[use path=\cloud];
            \draw[use path=\hill];
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[blend group=normal]
            \draw[use path=\cloud][line width=8];
            \draw[use path=\cloud][line width=6,white];
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[blend group=normal]
            \draw[use path=\hill][line width=8];
            \draw[use path=\hill][line width=6,white];
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]