Implementing Train Tracks in LaTeX
I currently try different styles in LaTeX and I found a beautiful article that uses train rail tracks:


and I tried to make at least the straight train track using other code from stack:
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,fit,fadings}
\newcounter{tracks}
% Layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{sleeper}
\pgfdeclarelayer{rail}
\pgfsetlayers{sleeper,rail,main}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{tracks}{final}{%
\state{final}{%
  \pgftransformreset 
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current path bounding box}{south west}}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@1}\pgfpointorigin%
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current path bounding box}{north east}}%
  \pgfcoordinate{@2}\pgfpointorigin%
  \node [fit=(@1)(@2), inner sep=\railsep+2*\railwidth] (@@) {};
  %
  % Create a fading for the track.
  \pgfinterruptpicture%
    \stepcounter{tracks}% 
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tracks\thetracks]
    \path[draw=transparent!0, line width=\railsep+2*\railwidth,
     postaction={draw=transparent!100, line width=\railsep}]
      \pgfextra{\pgfsetpath\pgfdecoratedpath};
    \useasboundingbox (@@.south west) (@@.north east);
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \endpgfinterruptpicture
  %
  % Draw sleepers.
  \ifx\sleeperlayer\emptylayer\else\pgfonlayer{\sleeperlayer}\fi%
  \draw [draw=\sleepercolor,line width=\sleeperlength, dash pattern=on \sleeperwidth off \sleepersep, every sleeper/.try]
    \pgfextra{\pgfsetpath\pgfdecoratedpath};
  \ifx\sleeperlayer\emptylayer\else\endpgfonlayer\fi%
  %
  % Draw the track
  \ifx\raillayer\emptylayer\else\pgfonlayer{\raillayer}\fi%
  \fill [path fading=tracks\thetracks, fit fading=false,
    fading transform={shift=(@@.center)}, fill=\railcolor]
   (@@.south west) rectangle (@@.north east);
   \ifx\raillayer\emptylayer\else\endpgfonlayer\fi%
}
}
\def\emptylayer{}
\tikzset{%
  track/.style={
    decoration=tracks, decorate
  },
  decorations/.cd,
    rail sep/.store in=\railsep,
    rail width/.store in=\railwidth,
    rail color/.store in=\railcolor,
    rail layer/.store in=\raillayer,
    sleeper sep/.store in=\sleepersep,
    sleeper width/.store in=\sleeperwidth,
    sleeper length/.store in=\sleeperlength,
    sleeper color/.store in=\sleepercolor,
    sleeper layer/.store in=\sleeperlayer,
    rail sep=5pt,
    rail width=1pt,
    rail color=black,
    rail layer=rail,
    sleeper sep=6pt,
    sleeper width=0.25pt,
    sleeper length=8pt,
    sleeper color=black,
    sleeper layer=sleeper,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [track] (0,0) to (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

But I am not satisfied with the result:

In the original, they seem to have a fixed length:

I do not know how to bend them in my code and I think the author uses fixed lengths and types and just connects them. Hence I wanted to ask if someone knows a manual for train tracks or can help me with these examples to recreate them. Thanks for any kind of guidance. It is just for fun!
One more example:

EDIT: Important, in the article the author states that 12 curved rails (the first one in the first picture) are needed to make a circle. So one curved rail is 1/12 of a circle.
2nd EDIT:
Thanks for the great answer! I figured out how to make different tracks. There is a good comment below the accepted answer asking how to recreate the last image witht the dashed lines and missing parts. Any ideas?

It should be noted that TikZ implements double lines as a single very wide line with a smaller white line line overlaid.   Both paths follow the center.

Have you looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198057/tikz-drawing-railway-tracks ?

@sgmoye Yes, but there it is one long rail, not a track made out of little small pieces.

Here's a different approach.

The turns have levels, by default this is level 0 (see /tikz/track turn level) where the radius is 2 while straight pieces have length 1.
The level changes the radius so that the turns stay parallel.

The sleepers aren't placed in absolutely fixed distances but spaced across a path operation.

The sleepers for level 0 (which is also used for a straight piece) are placed at positions 1/6, 3/6 = 1/2 and 5/6.

The sleepers for level 1 are placed at positions 1/8, 3/8, …, 7/8. This looks good enough in my opinion.

The keys are:

s places a straight piece in the current direction.

r and l place turns of the current level/radius to the right or the left.
Their argument overrides the default level.

track turn level changes the default level.

* places a track connection at the start.
If used outside of a to path operation, it uses the current orientation of the track. This can be overriden by using its argument.




Special keys that deal with tangents are:

save tangent = <name> saves the current “tangent”, i.e. current position and the current direction, as <name>.

continue tangent = <name> sets the previously named “tangent”.
Without an argument, the last saved tangent will be used.

save last tangent will automatically save the last “tangent” of the path.

set tangent point overrides the internal tangent point (managed by TikZ).

go to current point moves the pen to the current position.

turn around turns the direction of the path.


Also provided are macros \track and \ftrack which start a track or a “fake track” (the dashed path). It is setup so that a * will continue the last path where as >dir< sets the initial direction of the path.

The second picture shows that this is more made for a continuous path of track pieces instead of special combinations of tracks (switches or intersections).
Especially slip switches aren't that easy. At this point, this is a math question about the trigonometry of it all. In the very last track, I've guesstimated the magic number of 1.154545 for the straight pieces so that they align with the turns.

Depending on the task, the input syntax might needed change since there's no way to change the track lengths/radii without changing the xyz coordinate system.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pgfaddanchortonode[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \pgf@process{#3}\pgfsettransform{\csname pgf@sh@nt@#1\endcsname}\pgf@pos@transform@glob
    \edef\pgf@marshal{%
      \noexpand\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@sh@ma@#1\endcsname{%
        \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname pgf@anchor@\csname pgf@sh@ns@#1\endcsname @#2\endcsname{%
          \noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}}}%
    \pgf@marshal\endgroup}
\newcounter{tikztangent}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{tikztangentdirection}{0}{\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\tikz@tangent}{\tikz@last@position}}
\tikzset{
  turn around/.style={set tangent point={([turn]{#1}:-1)}, insert path={(\tikz@lastx,\tikz@lasty)}},
  set tangent/.code=\def\tikz@tangent{\pgfpointadd{\tikz@last@position}{\pgfpointpolar{180+#1}{1pt}}},
  set tangent point/.code=\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax\edef\tikz@tangent{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}},
  save last tangent/.code=\tikz@addoption{\stepcounter{tikztangent}\tikzset{save tangent=@\the\value{tikztangent}}},
  save tangent/.value required,
  save tangent/.code=\xdef\tikztangent@{#1}\pgfcoordinate{tangent-#1}{\tikz@last@position}%
                     \pgfaddanchortonode{tangent-#1}{tangent}{\tikz@tangent},
  continue tangent/.default=\tikztangent@,
  continue tangent/.style={insert path=(tangent-#1),
    /utils/exec=\pgf@process{\pgfpointanchor{tangent-#1}{tangent}}%
                \edef\tikz@tangent{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}},
  go to current point/.style={insert path={(\tikz@lastx,\tikz@lasty)}},
  offset/.code=\tikz@addoption{\pgfgetpath\tikz@temp\pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty\pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\tikztrack}{msd><}{%
  \path[#1]\pgfextra{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\tikzset{continue tangent}}%
    \IfValueT{#3}{\tikzset{set tangent={#3}}}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  arc/.style={to path={arc[{#1}]\tikztonodes}},
  %
  track line width/.initial=1pt,
  track width/.initial=2mm,
  track sleeper width/.initial=3mm,
  track connection length/.initial=3pt,
  %
  every track sleeper/.style={draw},
  every track connection/.style={draw, thick},
  %
  track sleeper/.code={\path[every track sleeper] (down:{.5*(#1)}) -- (up:{.5*(#1)});},
  track connection/.code 2 args={
    \path[every track connection]{
      [shift=(down:{.5*(#1)})] (down:{.5*(#2)}) -- (up:{.5*(#2)})}{
      [shift=(  up:{.5*(#1)})] (down:{.5*(#2)}) -- (up:{.5*(#2)})};},
  pics/track connection/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\tikzset{track connection={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track width}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track connection length}}}},
  pics/track sleeper/.style   ={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\tikzset{track sleeper=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track sleeper width}}},
  %
  track/.style={
    path only, save last tangent,
    */.style={insert path={pic[rotate=##1]{track connection}}},*/.default=tikztangentdirection,
    postaction={draw, line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track line width}, offset=.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track width})},
    postaction={draw, line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track line width}, offset=-.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track width})},
    every to/.append style={*/.style={edge node=pic[at start]{track connection}},track sleepers=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track sleepers'},edge node={pic[at end]{track connection}}}},
  %
  track sleepers'/.initial=0,
  track sleepers/0/.style={edge node={[behind path]pic[pos=1/6]{track sleeper}pic[pos=3/6]{track sleeper}pic[pos=5/6]{track sleeper}}},
  track sleepers/1/.style={edge node={[behind path]pic[pos=1/8]{track sleeper}pic[pos=3/8]{track sleeper}pic[pos=5/8]{track sleeper}pic[pos=7/8]{track sleeper}}},
  track sleepers/.style=track sleepers/#1/.try,
  %
  track/straight/.style 2 args={track sleepers'=0,insert path={to[{#1}]#1:1)}},
  track/turn/.style n args={4}{#2,
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro\tikztangentdirection{tikztangentdirection},
    track sleepers'={#1},
    insert path={to[arc={radius=2+2*(#1)*.268, start angle=#3, delta angle=#4}]()}},
  fake track/.style={save last tangent, densely dashed, track sleepers/.code=, draw, very thick},
  track shortcuts/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\track{\tikztrack{track}}\def\ftrack{\tikztrack{fake track}},
    track turn level/.initial=0,
    s/.style={track sleepers'=0,insert path={to[##1]([turn]right:1)}},
    l/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track turn level},
    l/.style={track/turn={##1}{}{\tikztangentdirection-90}{30}},
    r/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/track turn level},
    r/.style={track/turn={##1}{}{\tikztangentdirection+90}{-30}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[track shortcuts]
\track>0<[*, s, s, s, save tangent=1, r, l, s, r, r, r, r, r, r, s, s, s, s, r, r, r, r, r, r, s, s, s];
\track[continue tangent=1, s, s, s, track turn level=1, r, r, r, r, r, r, s, r=0, l=0];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[track shortcuts]
\track>90< [*, l];
\track>90< (right:1) [*, l]
           (right:1) [set tangent=90, r];
\track>60< (right:2) [*, s] coordinate (@)
      (@|-current subpath start) to[track sleepers=0, *] +(120:1);
\track>90< (right:3) [*, s];

\track>-30< (down:.7) [l, l, turn around=180, l, l, turn around=180, l, l];

\newcommand*\magic{1.154545}
\track (2.5,-2.5) to ++(60:\magic) to ++(60:\magic)
       [turn around=180, l, l, go to current point]
       to ++(120:\magic) to ++(120:\magic)
       [turn around=180, r, r, go to current point];
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[track shortcuts]
\track  >90<[*, l, l, l, l, r, l];
\ftrack*       [r, l];
\track *    [*, r, l, l, l, l, l, l, r];
\ftrack*       [l, r];
\track *    [*, l, r, l, l, l, l];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output




Awesome ... Nice one

Amazing work! Is it possible to leave an empty track? And to make these dashed lines between two rails like in the last picture of the question?

@calculatormathematical I've updated my answer with a new syntax that revolves around saving the current point and direction of a path and reusing it later. This means a path can be continues from another. This makes it very easy to switch between a proper track and a “fake” track.
